# Reading in file, trying to return 2D array of chars

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, character-arrays

Hey I'm trying to take in a file in function parameters and return a 2D char array, or 2D char pointer, or 2D Vector.. not sure exactly which I should use. I'm thinking 2D char array to keep it simple. Basically I do not know the length of each line from the file I'm going to read in so I'm not sure how long a regular array would be. I'm visualizing a regular piece of paper as a very large 2D array. This is what I've got so far, it's still Void as I don't know what to return yet..

```
void ReadFile(std::string &file)
{

    //This is a file reader object. This time I am passing the name of the file as an argument into the constructor.

    std::ifstream TheReader(file);
    int lineLength = 0;
    int numLines = 0;

    char linebreak = 13;
    char singleCharacter;
    if (TheReader.is_open())
    {
        TheReader.get(singleCharacter);


        if (singleCharacter != linebreak)
        {
            lineLength++;
            TheReader.get(singleCharacter);
        }
        else if (singleCharacter == 13)
        {
            numLines++;
        }


        std::vector<std::vector<int>> myVector;
        lineLength = 0;
        numLines++;

        TheReader.close();

    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Error. Unable to open file" << std::endl;
    }

}
```

Any input is good input! 
Cheers!

Comment: ??? Yet you read at max 2 chars from the input and don't even try to push their int value into that vector of vectors, which, btw, would not survive scope exit.

Comment: You want to get the lines? Use `std::getline` function.

Comment: I tried using std::getline(TheReader, what do I put here? array[0][1]?, char 13 (carriage return as delim)).

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to return a std::vector
Something like that

```
std::vector<std::string> ReadFile(const std::string &file)
{
    std::vector<std::string> output;
    std::ifstream TheReader(file.c_str());
    std::string line;
    while (std::getline(TheReader, line))
        output.push_back(line);
    return output;
}
```

Comment: Sorry I should clarify, I'm looking to have it start into the next line of the 2d array when it reaches a carriage return character. I'm trying to compare the current character to see if it's a carriage return if so, skip it and push next char to start of new array.

Comment: Thats what this code does. The second dimension of the array is infact the string itself. But you can treat it similar like a vector. E.g. this gives you the 3rd character of the 4th line: output[4][3]

Comment: whats not working with the code I posted? And why are you passing a vector reference as argument just to return it again? You don't need need the '\n' delimiter explicitly, thats the default.

Comment: I tried to use it but keep getting the error Vector subscript out of range. I figured this is because it's not delimiting the lines properly.

Comment: sorry, but you might want to start with a very basic programming tutorial on C++. E.g. here: http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LinuxTutorialC++STL.html or this one http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/lesson10.html

Comment: @Cellery72: I don't know how exactly you used this, but it very much appears that you try to work with your_vector[N] without knowing that your_vector actually has >= N+1 elements. Check your_vector.size() **before** you try to access it that way.